# ADO Parameterized Query: Cannot set CursorType/CursorLocation

Tags: sql-server, asp-classic, ado

I'm trying to write a function in ASP classic to do a safe parameterized query on a SQL Server database using ADO, and I want to return a recordset that is not forward only.

I can't find any guidance on how to use both parameters AND to control the cursor type/location.

The error I get is

> Command text was not set for the command object

Here is the code I have so far:

```
sub ParameterizedSQL2(ByRef RS, strSQL, param1)
    Set DB_Conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection") 
    SET rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet")
    DB_Conn.Open Application("ConnectionString")

    Set objCmd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
    ObjCmd.ActiveConnection = DB_Conn

    Set objParam = objCmd.CreateParameter("@PAR", adVarChar, adParamInput, 250)  
    objCmd.Parameters.Append(objParam)
    objCmd.Parameters("@PAR") = param1
    objCmd.CommandType = adCmdText
    ObjCmd.CommandText = strSQL 'The paramterized query of the form [SELECT * from Table WHERE Field=?]

    rs.Open objCMD, , adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic

    Set DB_Conn = nothing
    Set objCmd = nothing
    Set objParam = nothing
End sub
```

Comment: The error message indicates that `strSQL` is not getting any value. How are you calling the function?

Comment: **Tip:** Don't instantiate the `ADODB.Connection` let the `ADODB.Command` do it for you `ObjCmd.ActiveConnection = Application("ConnectionString")`, then when you call `ObjCmd.Close` both the `ADODB.Connection` and `ADODB.Command` will be closed and released from memory, no need for `Set DB_Conn = ` anymore! *That will shave your code by about 5 lines.*

Comment: Thanks - Error was because I simply was not passing the SQL string. Duh!